# How to change the visibility for the "logger" service on Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have recently upgraded from Symfony 3.4 to 4.4

The codebase is really large and there are a lot of references to `container->get('logger')` from all over the place.

I have been trying to make this service public, but not having any luck with any examples I can find.
Error:

> The "logger" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.

In my `service.yml` I have tried this with no luck:

```yaml
Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
 public: true

Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
 alias: 'logger'
 public: true

Psr\Log\LoggerInterface:
 alias: 'monolog.logger'
 public: true
```

How can I make the `logger` service public?

NOTE: in the upgrade from 3.4->4.4 we did not update the codebase to use Symfony Flex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would do this with a [Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html). (Docs are for 4.4, since that's the version you are using, current docs are [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html)).

Change your application `Kernel` so it implements `CompilerPassInterface`, and on the `process()` method you can manipulate the service container directly:

```
// src/Kernel.php
namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    // ...

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->getDefinition('monolog.logger')->setPublic(true);
    }
}
```

---

In any case, if I were you I'd investigate using something like [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-symfony) to automatically update your code. It even includes [a rule for this specific use-case](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-symfony/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#containergettoconstructorinjectionrector), converting the (ab)use of injected container and public services into proper dependency injection.

Comment: Hmm i couldnt get the service `logger` to work (as its an alias) and also using `getAlias('logger')` wouldnt work. However I did get `monolog.logger` to work so have updated the code to use this instead - testing now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't test the code myself. That's the general idea on how to manipulate the service container, you may  need to perform very small adjustments to apply the solution.

Comment: Yes I managed to make `monolog.logger` a public service and I have updated my referenced to use `monolog.logger`. I was not able to get `logger` working - though I didnt spend much time on trying as the easier (I had time pressures) option was to use `monolog.logger` - Thanks!

Comment: @Steve Can you please tell me the changes you made for this? I got the same issue. Did you add change on config.yml?

Comment: I tried updating all the config/services yml files but didnt have any luck. I have added a Answer with the changes I made :)